# Delete Specific Items from Filtered Table

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, excel-tables, listobject

I want to have a table filter and remove the items that are not needed. However, when I try to filter the four items that need to be removed, I receive the following error message - Compile error: Named argument not found.

The column I am filtering is 15.
The items I want to filter and remove are INF, IWC, ONF, OWC.  I only want to see COB.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
With Sheet2 
    With .ListObjects("Table13").DataBodyRange
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="INF", "IWC", "ONF", "OWC"
        .EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- If autofilter is activated in the table (ListObject), `ListObject.Range.AutoFilter` (the 4th line in your code) removes autofilter.
- It is important to verify the autofilter status first. If it is activated, proceed to eliminate any existing filters to show all data; otherwise, activate the autofilter.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [AutoFilter object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm537072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim oFilter As Object, bFilter As Boolean
    Dim rVisRng As Range, rRow As Range
    With Sheet2.ListObjects("Table13")
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            bFilter = True
            .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=15, _
            Criteria1:=Array("INF", "IWC", "ONF", "OWC"), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rVisRng = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rVisRng Is Nothing Then
            For Each rRow In rVisRng.Areas
                rRow.EntireRow.Delete
            Next
        End If
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        If Not bFilter Then .Range.AutoFilter ' disable AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ZulT Have your tried the code?

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Rows From Excel Table

- When filtering by multiple criteria, you need to put them in an array and set the `Operator` argument's parameter to `xlFilterValues`.
- Often, when dealing with an Excel table, you don't know (or care about) the index of the column but you know its title e.g. "Abbr". Instead of `15`, you can then use `.ListColumns("Abbr").Index`. Now you can risk-free insert and move columns and the code will still work. On the other hand, of course, if you change the title you're busted.

```vb
Sub DeleteRows()
    With Sheet2.ListObjects("Table13")
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter 15, Array("INF", "IWC", "ONF", "OWC"), xlFilterValues
        Dim vrg As Range
        On Error Resume Next
            Set vrg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        If Not vrg Is Nothing Then vrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I add this into an existing macro, it throws an error. I am removing the Sub DeleteRows() and End Sub and putting everything else into the existing macro.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Which error (number and description)? Is the code name (the one not in parentheses in the *Project Explorer*) of the sheet with the table `Sheet2`? If the tab name is `Sheet2`, use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")` instead. Did you rename your table? Does your table have even 15 columns?

Comment: Is this what you were suggesting I do @VBasic2008?    'With THisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") Sheet2.ListObjects("Table13")
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter 15, Array("INF", "IWC", "ONF", "OWC"), xlFilterValues
        Dim vrg As Range
        On Error Resume Next
            Set vrg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        If Not vrg Is Nothing Then vrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    End With'